# HLS on Android in browser

Tags: android-intent, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I developed HLS live video streaming server for iPad, it works well, you can see it, for example, here - http://www.ontvtime.com/general/ort-3.html
But when I try to play video on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with Android 4.1.2 - it doesn't work. Very long downloading, then video plays for about several seconds and then stops.

Are there any guide, tools and any examples of how to create live HLS video streams for Android, like it is for iOS? What steps should I do to find where is the error in my HLS streams or in playlists?

Answer (score 1):

Official site to make your video compatible with Android version
  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Try my solution : [converted mp4 file using ffmpegvis not playing JW player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654256/converted-mp4-file-using-ffmpegvis-not-playing-jw-player/20663864#20663864)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. There were 2 problems: the first is that iPad asks playlists only when it is needed but Android asks playlists very often. So I changed my logic of creating playlists. 
And the second problem is that Android do not understand removing media URI from playlists using EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE. I also changed my logic of creating playlists.

But then I encountered another problem in Android HLS, I think that it is a bug. I posted it here - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63959 and at the moment I don't know  a way of how to solve it.