# converted mp4 file using ffmpegvis not playing JW player

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, jwplayer, mov, video-conversion

Just i converted mov video file to mp4 file using ffmpeg. But the converted file is not playing JW player. Actual mp4 file videos working fine in all browsers. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is a superuser question. stack-overflow is just for programming and program related questions.

Comment: Thanks stephen.. But i get a solution for this issue .

Comment: Thanks all specially to Ethan.. Great to see the response from you. I fixed the issue. But my question is why MOV video files are not playing in JW player.

Answer (score -1):

*ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec acc -strict experimental -profile:v baseline -f mp4 -y mp4video.mp4*

Comment: You should test your commands first. You're forgetting the `-i` and the `-f mp4` is superfluous.

Comment: ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec acc -strict experimental -profile:v baseline -f mp4 -y mp4video.mp4

Comment: Again, using `-f` is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score -1):

My ffmpeg conversion comment is correct. But ffmpeg installation is the reason for the issue. I used the following command to convert:

> ffmpeg -i /uploads/sample.move -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slower -vpre main -level 21 -refs 2 -b 345k -bt 345k -threads 0 /uploads/sample.mp4

Comment: You mention that the ffmpeg installation is the issue but you do not explain what this issue actually is and how you fixed it.

Comment: While installing ffmpeg we have to add some lib module for conversion. That modules was not installed properly in my server. We reinstall the ffmpeg properly then issue fixed.

Comment: You should be more specific in case others are experiencing the same issue (whatever the issue may be as it is impossible to know from the limited amount of info you provided).